# Take string input on default index method in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to take input of username value on default mvc5 home page controller Index method. I already tried to do it like bellow `[Route("{Username?}")]` but it suppose to get value on url: `https://localhost:44330/myusername` but this url not hits the Index method. Can i do it without changing in `RouteConfig.cs` or how can i do it changing RouteConfig.cs even?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("{Username?}")]
        public ActionResult Index(string Username)
        {
            
            
                return View();
            
            
        }

       
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: This is an  HttpGet action. So it is called when someone requires to show Index.cshtml view, not when your user types a username in the Index.cshtml view and want to Post it

Comment: Check now. Forget what i do with this username value. I just want to take some input on this method by this url: `https://localhost:44330/myusername`

Comment: Do you have a view called _myusername_ in the View/Home folder? If yes what do you do in that view to call the Index view?

Comment: No. I will use this username value to find user info from database

Comment: You need an [HttpPost] Index action that receive the username (called when the user wants to post back to the server). The one above is a HttpGet (called when someone wants to show intially a View with the same name of the Action

Comment: I want to take input initially. i am not interested in post here

Comment: No i get: The resource cannot be found. error if i remove `?` when i visit this method from browser.

Comment: If you go to “ https://localhost:44330/Home/myusername” does it work?

Comment: No still not works. Error: The resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it from RouteConfig.cs. Example codes are bellow:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{username}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", username = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "ProjectNameSpace.Controllers" }
            );
```

Comment: Yea this one works but i would more happy if i could do it without changing  `RouteConfig.cs` But anyways thanks